# CSVHelper change/ manipulate headers before reading the csv

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Am not in control of what csv file we may get and they ted to have an extra '_' or year added to the name from time to time which does not match with the mapping I have done.
Tried

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(cultureInfo)
              {
                  PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.Replace("_", " "),
              };
config.PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => Regex.Replace(args.Header, @"2021", string.Empty);
List<CSVInvoiceLineDetail> CSVParsedDataList = new();
using TextReader reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config);
csv.Read();
csv.ReadHeader();
while (csv.Read())
{                             
    CSVParsedDataList.Add(csv.GetRecord<CSVInvoiceLineDetail>());
    // Do something with the record.
}
```

but it doesn't work the headers are still how they were originally. Can anyone point out what am doing wrong here ?

Comment: First thing that stands out to me is the fact that only the `Regex.Replace` will be executed, not replacing the underscore. Instead, assign a function to `PrepareHeaderForMatch` *once* and perform both replacements inside there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

```
          var config = new CsvConfiguration(cultureInfo)
          {
              PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.Replace("_", " ").Replace("2021","");,
          };
```

Or if you want to strip all numbers and underscores out of headers:

```
          var config = new CsvConfiguration(cultureInfo)
          {
              PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => Regex.Replace(args.Header, "[0-9_]", "")
          };
```

Note that here it is replacing underscore with nothing, not space, so some adjustment to your declared header attributes may be required